# I want to share link using BBM in webworks application is their any way to do that?

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I want to share link using BBM in webworks application is their any way to do that in os 7

Answer (score 1):

Yes!
You need to use the BBM Social Platform API and the BBM SDK.
Check here: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.bbm.platform.html